# How to Test login page without calling Backend services in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I have a login page which authenticates the user by sending a token from the backend. But I want to test my login page with protractor without calling backend service with a dummy token. How to do that??

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `spyON`, here what we do is, we won't make any API calls. Instead we will spy and return a mock data. Example:

```
spyOn(someObj, 'func').and.returnValue(42);
```

You can refer below links for more details:

https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Spy.html

https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/jasmine-spyon.html

Hope this will help.

Comment: when i click on submit button it hits  two services one for authentication and one for token generation.. How can i fake this in protractor??

Comment: You can create mock services for both and try spyOn for both.

Comment: i'm new to protractor can you please provide any link for mock in protractor?

Comment: Clone the repo and try npm run test. Hope this will help. https://github.com/anooprvarrier/angular-basics/blob/master/src/app/employee/employee.component.spec.ts